# export mysql table data with column header using vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net-2010

i want to export mysql table data with column heading to excel sheet. am using vb.net. but am not able to get table column heading in excel sheet. am getting only mysql table data.

```
my code
-------
 Dim i, j As Integer


    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim misValue As Object = System.Reflection.Missing.Value

    xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue)
    xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Sheets("sheet1")


    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            xlWorkSheet.Cells(i + 1, j + 1) = _
            ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item(j)
        Next
    Next

    xlWorkSheet.SaveAs("D:\vbexcel.xlsx")
    xlWorkBook.Close()
    xlApp.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Vb.net, but I had a similar issue and had to use the syntax:

IGNORE 1 LINES in the statement.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html (this is for importing, but the IGNORE 1 LINES syntax is described here...)